# CSS import fonts from otf

Tags: html, css, fonts

guys, I'm having trouble with importing fonts from an otf file

**main.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'testfont';
    src: url('fonts/test.otf');
}

.fonttest {
    font-family: 'testfont';
}
```

**main.html**

```
<p class="fonttest">TESTtest</p>
```

But still when I try start the homepage it shows the standard font of html.
When I use the inspector on my browser opera and chrome it says that the font was accepted

Comment: which font you apply

Comment: And you can verify in your dev tools that the font URL is correct and is correctly transferred to the client? And also, that the Opera version you are using supports the OTF font format?

Comment: _“When I use the inspector on my browser opera and chrome it says that the font was accepted”_ - no, it doesn’t. That only shows that you _specified_ a certain font family name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: testfont;
    src: url("fonts/test.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: And notably, `format("otf")` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your OTF font using @font-face like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: testfont;
    src: url("fonts/test.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: testfont;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("fonts/test.otf") format("opentype");
}
```